# SharePoint document library searchbox not working (InPlaceSearch)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-search

I am trying to make the SharePoint document library in-place searchbox working on the document names.

Current config :

- The Filename **managed property** is **searchable**.
- The **crawled properties** mapped to Filename are included in the **full-text index**.
- The content has been full crawled.
- When looking with the **Search Query Tool**, the Filename property has the good content.

Some documents in my library have a file name pattern as following "Doc-***Category***-***Title***.pdf" where Category and Title are variables. When I am looking for a category in particular I don't get any search results, even If I have documents whith this category in the file name.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint [doesn't return matches for partial word hits](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84959/sharepoint-search-not-showing-any-results-when-searching-partial-name-such-as-f).  Try adding a wildcard prefix to see if that's your issue.

```
Filename:*Category
```

Here is a [user voice request](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/330321-sharepoint-search/suggestions/33684439-partial-word-search-by-default-no-requirement-for) for partial word match support.